# iterate through li elements then .addclass css on some li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm iterating through li elements then applying css on some li elements that meets my criteria.

lets say i have a 15 total of **li** elements in **ul** then i will css class using javascript .addclass `hide_me` on li count 11 to 15.

this is the html:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>item 11</li>
    <li>item 12</li>
    <li>item 13</li>
    <li>item 14</li>
    <li>item 15</li>
</ul>
```

this i want to make using JavaScript/jquery

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li class="hide_me">item 11</li>
    <li class="hide_me">item 12</li>
    <li class="hide_me">item 13</li>
    <li class="hide_me">item 14</li>
    <li class="hide_me">item 15</li>
</ul>
```

So far i came up with this JavaScript code but its not working.

my Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.each($('.items'), function() {
       var children = $(this).find(">li");
       var count_items = children.length;

        for (var items = 11; items < count_items; items++) {
        //console.log(items); //output 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
        $(".items li:nth-of-type("+ items +")").addClass('.hideme'); // this is css selector by nth-type 
        }
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('ul li:gt(9)').addClass('addedclass')
```

```css
.addedclass{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>item 11</li>
    <li>item 12</li>
    <li>item 13</li>
    <li>item 14</li>
    <li>item 15</li>
</ul>
```

1. Use [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector. No need to iterate the li
2. Index start at `0`

> Description: Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

Comment: whats the purpose of gt(9). please expound. btw thanks fast solution @guradio

Comment: @AlexNewbie the `:gt()` uses index 0 as base and it will select the index greater than the specified. Meaning in our example since we need to select add to element 11 we need to specify index 10 but we start from zero making 9 the 10. I hope you can understand my explanation

Comment: @AlexNewbie glad to help..happy coding mate :)

Comment: whats wrong with my code above? why it doesn't work. just curious here

Comment: you dont need the for loop inside what your mistake is this `$.each($('.items')` there is no element with class `items`. you could just have `$.each($('li'), function(index,value) {` also you can pass index value and you can count the index..but you dont really need to loop :)

Comment: @AlexNewbie [check this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2ynw20zd/) if you want to really go with the loop. but like i said you dont need loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("li").each(function(k,v){
  if(k>9)
    $(this).addClass("hide-me");
});

// Apply css on class applied

$(".hide-me").css({ 'color':'red'});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sum1/yzubc169/